# Easy way of coding indices in large arrays and giving them values

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

Sorry I've only being coding for about a week and this question is probably very simple. I'm using Objective-C and I started learning about arrays and strings. I understand them but if I am making a very large array with hundreds of different strings it would take a long time to hard code all of the values and strings in. So I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. Instead of going

```
char listOfString[300];
listOfString[0] = "ha";
listOfString[1] = "hi";
```

if there was an easier way instead of coding all the values and and indices.

Please keep all of your answers or comments to a very simple level as I haven't been programming for long.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to specify the strings somehow. If you can describe an algorithm to generate them, you can use that to create the array at run time (or write a program to spit out the source).  But if it's just random, unrelated strings, you'll have to hardcode them.

Comment: `char listOfString[300]` is an array of `char`, not strings.  You'd want something like `char listOfString[300][11]` if you wanted 300 C strings with 10 characters each.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your notation here is wrong.  However, your question is about creating an array of strings without typing them in.  You can always store the strings in a file and write code to read each of the strings from the file and then add them to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without trying this,

```
char listOfString[300];
listOfString[0] = "ha";
listOfString[1] = "hi";
```

This is the Objective-c version of the thing you need,
*(mutable array is a variable length array)*

```
NSMutableArray *myStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myStringArray addObject:@"ha"];
[myStringArray addObject:@"hi"];
```

**How to access them ?**

calling [myStringArray objectAtIndex:number], will return you the object in that particular index, hence

```
NSLog(@"%@",[myStringArray objectAtIndex:0]); //prints->ha
NSLog(@"%@",[myStringArray objectAtIndex:1]); //prints->hi
```

Answer (score 0):

> I started learning about arrays and strings. I understand them

I don't think you do. You say you are learning Objective-C, but your example uses C strings and C arrays - not Objective-C. Don't confuse C strings / C arrays with Objective-C NSStrings and NSArrays. You will just about always use the latter. And NSArrays give you a nice notation for constructing them:

```
NSArray* arr = @[@"ha", @"hi", @"ho"];
```

It's good that you are learning C, since Objective-C is a superset of C, but it is Objective-C you'll be using most of the time.

Comment: And you could probably do worse than start reading my book right from the beginning: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html